# Subscribing to main app events without loading the plugin into the main app domain

Tags: c#, plugins, dll, appdomain

I have a main application which loads a plugin into a separate app domain. In that plugin I am subscribing to an event on object passed from the main app. Creating the plugin in a separate app domain will load the plugin dll into that domain but subscribing to an event on main app object will cause the plugin dll to be loaded into the main app domain too.

I want to be able to unload the plugin domain (which works) but I also need to be able to replace the plugin dll which I cannot currently do because that dll is loaded in the main app domain (because of that subscription).

Here is a sample code that resembles my actual code (for brevity):

I have an interface called IContract which is used to instantiate the plugin:

```
namespace PluginShared
{
    public interface IContract
    {
        void Init(IHostObject hostObject);
        void Shutdown();
    }
}
```

It resides in a separate PluginShared.dll. That interface defines 2 methods, Init for passing an object created in the main app and Shutdown to do the necessary cleanup in plugin before the plugin's app domain is unloaded.

IHostObject is in the same PluginShared.dll and looks like this:

```
namespace PluginShared
{
    public interface IHostObject
    {
        event Action ValueChanged;
    }
}
```

This interface is implemented by HostObject in the main app:

```
public class HostObject : MarshalByRefObject, IHostObject
{
    public event Action ValueChanged;

    public void Foo()
    {
        if (ValueChanged != null)
            ValueChanged();
    }
}
```

The main app code loads the plugin, calls Init and passes HostObject instance to plugin. Then calls Shutdown on the plugin and unloads the plugin domain.

```
private void LoadUnloadPlugin()
{
    IHostObject hostObject = new HostObject();

    AppDomain pluginAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("PluginAppDomain");

    IContract plugin = (IContract)pluginAppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(@".\Plugin1.dll", "Plugin1.Plugin1");

    plugin.Init(hostObject);
    plugin.Shutdown();

    AppDomain.Unload(pluginAppDomain);
}
```

The plugin is it its own Plugin1.dll:

```
namespace Plugin1
{
    public class Plugin1 : MarshalByRefObject, IContract
    {
        IHostObject myHostObject;

        public void Init(IHostObject hostObject)
        {
            myHostObject = hostObject;
            myHostObject.ValueChanged += OnValueChanged;
        }

        public void Shutdown()
        {
            myHostObject.ValueChanged -= OnValueChanged;
            myHostObject = null;
        }

        private void OnValueChanged()
        {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So again, the issue is that when myHostObject.ValueChanged += OnValueChanged; executes, it will load Plugin1.dll into main app domain which will lock the dll and thus prevent me to delete it.

Btw. I have many IHostObject like interfaces which define different ValueChanged like events fired by different objects. Also in general, my plugins do not subscribe to all object's events. I am mentioning this because ValueChanged event in the sample code above could be easily replaced with a method in IContract which would be called for each plugin instead of firing an event but my real implementation calls for more event-like approach.

So is there a way/technique/pattern I could use in order to be able to get selected notifications/events from the main app without loading the plugin dll into main app domain?